# Abrir ventana emergente con react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola a todos que pena los molesto, es que tengo una duda, lo que pasa es que estoy intentando abrir una ventana emergente en react con el método window.open de JS, dado que tengo que cargar un componente en la ventana actual donde se encuentra el usuario y otra aparte donde se carga otro componente, ejecutando estas dos acciones al tiempo, pero estoy teniendo un problema y es que al abrir la ventana emergente me saca  Not Found y me dicen que es porque pierde el contexto  esta nueva ventana de la aplicación de React esto en un ambiente de laboratorio, porque en Desarrollo no me pasa esto, en desarrollo funciona todo bien,  y me dice el equipo que es porque al abrir la otra ventana esta pierde el contexto, entonces mi pregunta es:
¿Como puedo abrir una ventana emergente ya sea pasando le el contexto de la aplicación o  con algún método similar history.push() para abrir la nueva ventana? GRACIAS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
if(response.data === "") {
      window.open(`/PdfP8/${idBill}/${BillNumber}/${dniProvider}`, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
      history.push(`/Auditory/${idBill}/${BillNumber}/${dniProvider}`);
   }
```

Comment: primero te sugiero verificar la ruta..es decir la ruta completa...sea htpp....o https://loquesea.com/lala/lala2....

Comment: luego de ello si los parametros los pasas directamente por URL abre una pestaña en tu navegador e ingresalos desde alli

Comment: Ya hice esto sigue con el miemos problema.

Comment: entonces significa que tu url esta mal.. o que los parametros pasados estan mal o no existen verifica que exista dicha ruta.. ala que haces referencia

Comment: Recuerda que si me funciona correctamente en ambiente de Desarrollo, en Laboratorio es donde no funciona, yo creo que es porque el servidor esta tomando esa ruta como archivo fisico, y como es una URL de react este no la encontrará, entonces lo que habría que hacer es pasar le un contexto de la aplicación principal a la otra. Lo que yo no se es como hacerlo.

Comment: Saludos, tengo entendido que es una mala práctica lo que buscas lograr (pero la verdad es que solo lo tengo entendido por algunos comentarios que he leído).

Este link puede servirte para lograr lo que buscas, tiene un ejemplo sencillo https://hackernoon.com/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202

Comment: Ya lo solucione, era problemas del dominio. 
<BrowserRouter basename="/dominio">

Answer (score 0):

La solución en realidad era especificar el dominio donde se esta confirgutan react-router-dom:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/dominio">
```